# Adding the GET information to POST request before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a calendar that I click on a certain date, then I send it as a GET to a form file, so I have a form on the url: www.mydomain/form.php?date=2017-11-12 for example. 
When the user submits the form, I need to also send the date along with the form fields.

How can I add the date on the GET to the POST request?

Edit: some code:

on the calendar.php I have the following request upon any date click:

```
window.open("http://mydomain/form.php?date=" + currentDate);
```

Now on the form.php, the URL is showing:

```
 http://mydomain/form.php?date=20170430
```

(It's just a simple form (I am currently testing):)

```
<form action="send.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So I need to send the first name, last name and the date with the POST request

Comment: Where is the code? I cannot read your mind.

Comment: So you want to add query parameters to a POST. Depending on the framework that's being used there are different ways to do this. So, like Robert said, please share your code, or at least some more information about the tools/frameworks that you use.

Comment: I edited the post, but it's really nothing to do with frameworks, it's just adding the information from the GET to the POST eventually

Comment: Well there's a difference in having as query parameter or in the form itself. I suggest using the hidden field as suggested by the answer provided. In PHP you can then retrieve it just like the firstname/lastname

Comment: Thanks! That did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `hidden` input

```
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?= $_GET['date']; ?>">
```

Comment: Your solution seemed correct, and I was thinking why isn't it working?!
Then I saw you forgot a semicolon - $_GET['date'];
 Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind function on submit button

```
$('[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('form[action="send.php"]').prop('action', 'http://mydomain/form.php?date=' + currentDate);
    $('form[action="send.php"]').submit();
});
```

It will change `action` attribute of form defore submiting data;